# Why doesn't the following code throw an error when we create a new instance?

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, es6-class

```js
class Person {}

let agent = new Person(50);
console.log(agent);
```

We haven't defined a `constructor` method on the `Person` class nor does the Person class `inherit (extend)` from an another class which has a constructor method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All classes in javascript have a default constructor method if the programmer does not define one. Try this in inspector:

```
class Person {}
console.log(Person);
```

and you'll be able to see the default constructor Javascript applies.

Comment: To add onto this, the reason for this is that all classes _ARE_ constructor functions. There's no differentiating between a class and its constructor in javascript.

Comment: @Declan McKelvey-Hembree Thanks for the reply.

So I tried the code you suggested.

```console.log(Person); 
// [Function: Person]
```

. It logged `[Function: Person]`. So, does this mean that default constructor method is a function named `Person`? In other words JS automatically sets up the constructor method for us incase we don't explicity define one?

Comment: Ah, in my inspector it actually shows you the class properties!

But yes that is what's happening.